# Prove that every non-abelian group of order $8$ has a $2$-dimensional irreducible character all of whose values are integers.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, galois-theory, characters

> Prove that every non-abelian group of order $8$ has a $2$-dimensional irreducible character all of whose values are integers.

I get that if $G$ is non abelian it must have an irreducible representation $>1$ and this implies that
$$8=1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+2^2$$
is the only possibility. Hence unique $2$-dimensional irreducible character,

I cannot see how to show that all its values will be integers. I feel this question may need some Galois theory that I am not very familiar with.

EDIT: I have the following hints.

$1)$ If $\chi$ is a character then so is $\sigma(\chi)$ for every automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{C}$.

$2)$ If $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is fixed by every automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ then $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This is definitely the _wrong_ way of solving the problem, but there are only two nonabelian groups or order $8$; you can find such a character explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider complex conjugation as an automorphism of $\mathbb C$. The complex conjugate of a character is also a character. You only have one character of degree $2$, so that implies something about the values.

Do you know that the values of a character are algebraic integers? Here, they are the sums of eigenvalues of matrices which satisfy $M^4=I$ (the orders of elements in a non-abelian group of order $8$ all divide $4$), and therefore satisfy $\lambda^4=1$. So if you don't know a general theorem about algebraic integers, you can simply list the possible sums of two eigenvalues, and see what the possibilities are.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I knew that - thanks for reminding me. I was thinking of automorphisms which fix $\mathbb R$ - but this is a technicality the answer can do without (especially as the question is working over $\mathbb Q$), so I've edited it out altogether per your comment.

Comment: @MarkBennet Your first paragraph means that the values will all be real. I know from a theorem that the character have to be algebraic integers but this doesnt imply they are integers. Or does it?

Comment: @sandstone I was picking up from the other answer a possible factor of $2$ which did not immediately exclude half integer values - any rational values are integers. But here you can just compute the cases.

Comment: I actually used the fact that character values are algebraic integers to convince myself that the factor of $2$ wasn't a problem.  This answer is a much more elegant way to look at it, because it proves in one sentence that a character which is unique of given degree always takes integer values.

Comment: I have a theorem that says $\text{algebraic integers} \cap \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}$. Does this work now?

Answer (score 6):

If $\chi_1, \ldots , \chi_4$ are the degree $1$ characters, and $\chi_5$ is the degree $2$ character, then what is $\chi_1 + \chi_2 + \chi_3+ \chi_4 + 2\chi_5$?

Comment: I dont see how youve got this or where it goes

Comment: @sandstone, the given sum is (by general theorey) the character of the regular representation, and therefore its value on an element of $g$ is $0$ (if $g \neq 1$) or $8$ (if $g=1$). This lets you write the values of the two-dimensional character in terms of the one-dimensional characters.

Comment: @Stephen I understand your explanation but I dont have explicitly $\chi_1,\chi_2,\dots,\chi_5$ so how could I evaluate it

Comment: Nor do I want to find them explicitly preferably

Comment: @sandstone: You don't need to find them. They are 1-dimensional characters of an abelian group of order $4$, so their values are roots of unity. Also, if they aren't real valued then, w.l.o.g., you can assume that $\chi_4=\overline{\chi_2}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And since the abelian group cannot be cyclic (being the quotient by a central subgroup), they must in fact be integer valued.

Comment: Ahh. Indeed, @Tobias. Well spotted!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How is it the quotient of a central subgroup? What does this mean?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How is it an abelian group?

Comment: @sandstone The $1$-dimensional characters are the characters of the abelianization, which happens to be the quotient by the center when the group has order $8$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Why does it happen when the group has order 8? and why cant it be cyclic? and why does this imply integer valued?

Comment: @sandstone The quotient of a non-abelian group by its center is never cyclic (this is a quite well-known result, and it is not too hard to prove as an exercise). Thus, in this case it must be a group where all elements have order dividing $2$, so the only possible values of the irreducible characters are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: ...okay, this approach wasn't as straightforward as I hoped.

Answer (score 2):

There only exist two non-abelian groups of order 8, they are $Q_8$ and $D_8$, you can compute the character table of each of them but spoiler: they both have a 2 dimensional irreducible character (the last character of the table)

Since there are only two such groups I think is more effective to just compute the tables.

Comment: Probably, the idea is to solve the question without using that fact that $Q_8$ and $D_8$ are the only non-abelian groups of order $8$.

Comment: A disagree. You learn more representation theory by not using this fact. (Although one thing you learn from this approach is that two nonisomorphic groups can have the same character table.)

Comment: Yes, although this two groups are not isomorphic they do have the same character table... And actually I think solving the character tables for $Q_8$ and $D_8$ is a very good exercise to understand a little more about representations theory.